# Using jQuery to vertically position an image

Tags: jquery, css

I have an image *.personal* that I want to center vertically within *.personal-row* (itself inside *.row-main*) both on page load and when I resize. A typical *vertical-align: middle;* didn't work, so I thought it'd be logical to take the height difference between *.personal* and *.row-main*, divide it by two, and give the image that padding on top and on bottom. This would effectively vertically align it. I also only wanted that to actuate at desktop sizes hence the conditional. For some reason, the padding becomes absolutely enormous as I resize.

Here's my code:

```
$('.personal').css({'height':((0.5*$('.jumbotron').height())+'px')});
  if($(window).width() > 720){
    var originalPadding = (($('.row-main').height() - $('.personal').height()) / 2);
    $('.personal').css({'padding-top': originalPadding + 'px'});
    $('.personal').css({'padding-bottom': originalPadding + 'px'});
  }
  $( window ).resize(function() {
      $('.personal').css({'height':((0.5* $('.jumbotron').height()) +'px')});
      //row height - image height / 2 = padding
      if($(window).width() > 720){
        var centeredPadding = (($('.row-main').height() - $('.personal').height()) / 2);
        $('.personal').css({'margin-top': centeredPadding + 'px'});
        $('.personal').css({'margin-bottom': centeredPadding + 'px'});
      }
  });
```

It makes sense in my head but for some reason isn't working properly. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Stop the JS nonsense, and use CSS. https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/, https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know you're asking to debug your js but would css flexbox not work for something like this?

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are supporting really old browsers, I would also strongly recommend using flexbox for two reasons: performance and accessibility.

Although it might not be a huge overhaul for many devices, you may run into issues with slower devices (like mobile phones) that load the JS later than desired which causes jankiness in how your page is displayed. In addition, it's a lot of calculation for something that practically all modern browsers can do natively now; so it's wasted code.

Secondly, as far as accessibility goes, it's optimal to keep as much styling out of JavaScript as much as possible in the event that the user's JavaScript is turned off or is not working for whatever reason.

In terms of how you would style it, I am assuming your content HTML is something like:

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="personal-row">
    <img class="personal" src="..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

So the respective CSS styles (including vendor prefixes) would be:

```css
.personal-row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: .personal-row is inside .row-main, but otherwise you have it down. However, it seems that this code had no affect on the position of the row vertically. It doesn't look like it's being overridden by Bootstrap unless you believe otherwise.

Comment: It's hard to debug without the actual HTML/CSS you're using since it's likely that there is some conflicting factor. If the vertical position is not being affected, it's likely because the height of the flex-container is only set to the content's height as opposed to the container.

If you put a border or outline around the containing element, you should be able to see what the height is and that might help you debug what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I would also opt for CSS, but you want to use jQuery. You write:

```
$('.personal').css({'height':((0.5*$('.jumbotron').height())+'px')});
```

etc.

For setting CSS pixel sizes it's usually necessary to write them in quotation marks (as a string), like

```
$('.personal').css({'height':'48px'});
```

Instead you can use a variable containing that string ( 48px), but not the string without quotes. I would use variables for getting the height first, then calculating the new height and using the result like this:

```
var height1 = $('.jumbotron').height());
var height2 = 0.5 * height1 +'px';    
$('.personal').css({'height': height2});
```

(might be a little bit complicated, but it works)